# Remove whitespace left of an array

Tags: arrays

I would like to display equations one on top of the other with a large brace on the left, with the `array` environment for instance. However, there always is a consequential white space between the brace and the equations :

[image]

Code for the above example :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\( \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} x^2 + y^2 = R \\ x>0 \end{array} \right. \)
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to remove said white space ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Simply use the `cases` environment instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The environment `{array}` adds a length equal of `\arraycolsep` on both sides of the array. In the documentation of `amsmath`, you read:

> The extra space of \arraycolsep that array adds on each side is a
> waste so we remove it [in {matrix}] (perhaps we should instead remove
> it from array in general, but that’s a harder task).

In order to delete those spaces, you have to add `@{}` in the preamble in order to replace the `\arraycolsep` by nothing (the `{}` in `@{}`).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\( \left\lbrace \begin{array}{@{}l@{}} x^2 + y^2 = R \\ x>0 \end{array} \right. \)
\end{document}
```

[image: Result of above code]

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Bernard in the comments, you could use the `cases` environment from `amsmath`. Alternatively, you could reduce the spacing between the brace and the equations by placing `@{}` before the `l` column specified in the `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
Original: \( \left\lbrace \begin{array}{l} x^2 + y^2 = R \\ x>0 \end{array} \right. \)

With \verb|cases|: \( \begin{cases} x^2 + y^2 = R \\ x>0 \end{cases} \)

Reducing space: \( \left\lbrace \begin{array}{@{}l} x^2 + y^2 = R \\ x>0 \end{array} \right. \)
\end{document}
```

[image]

In the third example, you could also adjust the spacing according to your needs, since the `@{}` will place what's between the brackets at that place in every row of the array. So a space can be added by replacing `@{}` with `@{\,}` or `@{\;}`, for instance.

Comment: That's perfect, thanks